How to use Blender's internal Python version/libraries with PYTHONPATH env in use
I am using a system environment variable PYTHONPATH to use some Python libraries in Houdini. However, this seems to conflict with Blender. For example, I have numpy installed and this breaks Blender's FBX importer. Is it possible to make Blender ignore PYTHONPATH env variable and just use its own internal Python libs?

Do you use --python-use-system-env?

No, just using the normal shortcut that was added to my Start menu:
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\blender-launcher.exe

What is the output of blender -b --python-expr "import sys; print(*sys.path, sep='\n')" and the same but with --factory-startup.


the PYTHONPATH should not be used unless you pass --python-use-system-env to Blender.


So if the PYTHOHNPATH is interfering with Blender's startup, that's something that should be fixed.

https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/115648#issuecomment-1076172
As a workaround you can create a .bat file with clearing PYTHONPATH and your Blender path:
set PYTHONPATH=
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\blender.exe"


Thanks unwave, this works for me and I have commented on the forum post.
